# Multivariable calculus, tangent lines and normal vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, orthogonality

A wording question here;

"How can you know that the tangent line to an intersection (of two surfaces) is orthogonal to the surfaces normal vectors?"

Comment: Depends on the definition of each of those terms.

Comment: @Chappers What do you mean? Do you need the functions that are intersecting? Because, as I understood it, this is a general attribute that always applies, but maybe I was wrong about that. :-)

Comment: I mean, what are the definitions of tangent and normal you are using? One definition of the normal is that it is perpendicular to the tangent space at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a point on a curve. The normal vector to a surface is orthogonal to a tangent plane in that point and a tangent vector of a curve lies in the tangent plane.